# Deserializing XML from Soap call into Array of Objects

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-deserialization

I am trying to make a soap call and deserialize the answer I receive back. The soap call is made correctly but I don't manage so far to deserialize the answer into an object. Specifically speaking, the XML contained in the answer is an array of repeated data. As you can guess I want to create an array of objects out of it. I have checked other similar questions but so far none worked. Let's start by defining the whole XML.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">ThisIsATry/RetrieveResponse</a:Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <RetrieveResponse xmlns="ThisIsATry">
      <RetrieveInsurersResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThisIsATry" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <b:Errors xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
        <b:Message>Selected 2 records</b:Message>
        <b:Results xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
          <c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
            <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <c:Key>PersonId</c:Key>
              <c:Value>1</c:Value>
            </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <c:Key>Name</c:Key>
              <c:Value>Mike</c:Value>
            </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          </c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
          <c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
            <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <c:Key>PersonId</c:Key>
              <c:Value>2</c:Value>
            </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <c:Key>Name</c:Key>
              <c:Value>Henry</c:Value>
            </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          </c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
        </b:Results>
        <b:Warnings xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
      </RetrieveInsurersResult>
    </RetrieveResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The part I need to use is:

```
    <b:Results xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
        <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          <c:Key>PersonId</c:Key>
          <c:Value>1</c:Value>
        </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          <c:Key>Name</c:Key>
          <c:Value>Mike</c:Value>
        </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      </c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
      <c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
        <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          <c:Key>PersonId</c:Key>
          <c:Value>2</c:Value>
        </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          <c:Key>Name</c:Key>
          <c:Value>Henry</c:Value>
        </c:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      </c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
    </b:Results>
```

As you can see there are 2 "objects" of type **c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>**. Each object contains 2 properties of type **c:KeyValueOfstringstring** . Finally, each one of these properties contains a **key** and a **value** . What I need is an array of **c:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring**, containing an array of **c:KeyValueOfstringstring** and the relative informations. I tried to represent this data in my c# code with the following classes:

```
public class ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring
{
    [XmlElement("ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring")]
    public KeyValueOfstringstring[] Value { get; set; }

}

public class KeyValueOfstringstring
{
    [XmlElement("KeyValueOfstringstring")]
    public KeyValue Pair { get; set; }

}

public class KeyValue
{
    [XmlElement("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Value")] 
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The way I deal with the response so far is:

```
var result = client.UploadString(dataBaseConnectionString, soapTemplate); //calls the serive and brings back the XML
var document = XDocument.Parse(result); //gives back the first XML I posted in this question
var results = document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Results"); //gives back the 2nd XML I posted

xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("c", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");
var oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SoapResponse[]));

//this part is wrong..
using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(results.ToString())))
{
      var responseObj = (ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring)oXmlSerializer.Deserialize(mem);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is it not possible to create proxy class of the WCF service? That will create all the required data structures.

Comment: That looks like XML generated by [tag:wcf].  Can you generate a client automatically from the service's wsdl?  See [Generating a WCF Client from Service Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/generating-a-wcf-client-from-service-metadata), [How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client) and [How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it so happens, `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring` is the element name that [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) chooses when serializing a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so you're going to have a much easier time using that serializer to deserialize your XML.

First, introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class DataContractSerializerExtensions
{
    public static T ToContractObject<T>(this XContainer doc, DataContractSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)(serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T))).ReadObject(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can parse your XML into a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` as follows:

```
var dictionaries = document.Descendants()
    .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring")
    .Select(d => d.ToContractObject<Dictionary<string, string>>())
    .ToList();
```

Then later you can map the list of dictionaries to your preferred model.

However, if for whatever reason you must use `XmlSerializer`, instead introduce the following extension method and data model:

```
public static partial class XmlSerializerExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this XContainer doc, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)(serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "KeyValueOfstringstring", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
public class KeyValueOfstringstring
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Key", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
public class ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "KeyValueOfstringstring", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
    public List<KeyValueOfstringstring> KeyValueOfstringstring { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
var results = document.Descendants()
    .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring")
    .Select(d => d.ToObject<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>())
    .ToList();
```

Notes:

- I use [`XNode.CreateReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560(v=vs.110).aspx) to return an `XmlReader` from which an `XNode` can be deserialized directly.  This avoids the requirement to convert selected node(s) back to a string representation and then re-parse.
- The namespace for the `<b:Results>` node is `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ThisIsATry"`.  This namespace feels... provisional.. so I avoided using it in my answer.

All this being said, since the XML looks like it might have been generated by a [wcf service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx), is there any chance the service provides [WSDL Metadata](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-ws-addr-metadata-20070904/)?  If so you may be able to generate a client automatically.  See

- [Generating a WCF Client from Service Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/generating-a-wcf-client-from-service-metadata)
- [How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client)
- [How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

For documentation on how this can be done.

Comment: It's some very old legacy code that I cannot touch in order to use a client.. but your solution is amazing! You explained everything step by step and it works perfectly.. thank you big time for your help!

Comment: I need exact opposite of this.. I need to serialize an array of object inside an object using C#. Can any one guide me on it... Any link or documentation would help. Thanks

Comment: @Renascent - you should probably ask a new question (with a [mcve]) as the format for questions here is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) - the answers to which should answer that specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Results").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace nsC = results.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("c");

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = results.Descendants(nsC + "KeyValueOfstringstring")
               .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(nsC + "Key"), y => (string)y.Element(nsC + "Value"))
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }

}
```